# When is the function above its obliques asymptote?

Tags: functions

$y = 2x + \frac{3(x − 1)} {x+1}$

How to determine the values for x for which a function such as this one is below its oblique asymptote?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The asymtote is $y=2x+3$. The function is $$y=2x+3-\frac{6}{x+1}$$

So you want to solve $$\mathrm{function}-\mathrm{asymptote} =-\frac{6}{x+1} \geq 0$$

Comment: how do we solve this inequality?

Comment: Have you even tried yourself?

Comment: yes yes. wouldn't (x+1) become zero?

Comment: Yes, and then it is undefined. To the right it is negative, and to the left it is positive.

Answer (score 1):

**Some background knowledge:**

If a function $f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$, where degree of polynomial $P(x)=$degree of polynomial $Q(x)+1$,

then we have $y=f(x)=g(x)+\frac{c}{Q(x)}$, where degree of polynomial $g(x)=1$ and $c\in{\Bbb{R}}$.

And we call $y=g(x)$ is the **Oblique Asymptote**.

So return to your question:

As $y = 2x + \frac{3(x − 1)} {x+1}=\frac{2x^2+5x-3}{x+1}=2x+3-\frac6{x+1}$

So can you say which function is the $g(x)$ I mentioned, that is, the Oblique Asymptote?